# My sticky positioned element isn't acting like it should

Tags: css, position, sticky

Usually, I don't have any issues with the sticky position property.
However, I can't figure out why my div isn't behaving so.

See the issue here : [my link](https://cura.siladev.com/paul-maudrette-practitioners-6)

The reservation part `.practitionerRight #reservation` on the right is wrapped within a higher div `.practitionerRight`.

It should stick to top: 80px but it doesn't. I read the Stack Overflow topics about sticky positioning but couldn't find the solution there.

Here is the actual css code :

```
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 80px;
```

Thanks to those who will try to help me.

Comment: You're not showing enough of your code. There's no way to help with the information you provided.

Comment: Try `position: fixed` instead, and add a `background-color` to `#reservation`

Comment: Thought of fixed position but having a problem with overflowing header and footer.

Comment: You can check the attached link @RolandoYera to see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're div with the id of `main` has `overflow-x: hidden`. That div is the parent of the child that you want sticky and overflow hidden doesn't play well with position: sticky. Remove the `overflow-x: hidden` css and it works (line #118 in your style.css):

```
#main{
min-height:100%;
width: 100%;
/* overflow-x: hidden; */ //remove this
}
```

There's nothing overflowing, anyhow.

Comment: That was it, thanks mate !